# Google Analytics API sends ga:transactionid as a string although parses it as an integer

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I faced an issue, while doing the report via BI:
Failed to parse data 'B10109393939' for column Transaction id.

I tried to fix it by applying a filter

```
    {
        "dimensionFilterClauses": [
            {   
                  "filters" : [
               {
                   "dimensionName" : "ga:transactionid",
                   "operator":"NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN",
                   "expressions": [
                   "0"
      ]
            }
         ]
       }
     ]
```

But it didn't help me much, because the goal is to include all transaction IDs and then transform Transaction id column  to the string type.

Could anyone let me know how to change the ga:transactionid dimension request so that it won't be parsed as an integer?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions in Google Analytics are strings so you can't handle them with filters as if they were numbers.

You have to try to create a regex as a filter that meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, but apparently I cannot use REGEX operator with dimensions `Domo is ready, but Domo received an error requesting the data. (Bad/Malformed Request). Invalid value at 'report_requests[0].dimension_filter_clauses[0].filters[0].operator' (TYPE_ENUM), "REGEX"`

Comment: I used this expression: `                       "dimensionName" : "ga:transactionid",
                       "operator":"REGEX",
                       "expressions": [
                       "[a-zA-Z0-9]"`